# Redirect domain to another domain for Wix site

Tags: domains, redirects

I have two domains and they both point to the same `Wix.com` site. When I navigate to either domain the URL is always for that domain. The domains are both managed through domain.com

I want to be change this so that anytime domain1 is visited it redirects to domain2, so when visiting the Wix.com site it will never show domain1 as the URL.

The changes need to be made in the DNS records or in Wix.

EDIT: corrected last sentence of first paragraph

Comment: What do you mean that "the domains are both on `example.com`?"  Does that mean that they are subdomains like `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller , sorry that should have read "The domains are both managed through domain.com".  My apologies

Answer (score -1):

"The changes need to be made in the DNS records or in Wix." are you sure?

If I was doing this, I would use a .htaccess redirect

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How do you get to the .htaccess on Wix.com?

Comment: @user1150103, apologies, I misread the question and thought one was a wix site and the other was redirecting to it, in which case there might be a .htaccess file.  But that would be a way to make it work.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Unfortunately, everything needs to be managed through domain.com or Wix.com

Comment: doesn't domain.com include redirection?

Comment: not that I am aware of. I have checked the menus and I can't find anything

Comment: Transfer the domain to somewhere that does include redirection

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Steve, I ended up using Redirect Pizza. So domain.com -> redirect pizza -> Wix